# wx python turn off screen paint during update

Tags: user-interface, wxpython

I have a wx python aplication that necessitates updating many images on the screen programmatically. This works fine on Unix but looks like a dog's breakfast on Windows

Is there something like Excel's

```
Application.Screenupdating = False
```

that will turn off the screen paintng while the process is underway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
frame.Freeze()
.... do update
frame.Thaw()
```

see: http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Window.html?highlight=freeze#Window.Freeze

Comment: Thanks Werner. I'll give it a try